# Right strategy of using Bottom Navigation bar with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

The official documentation of Compose Navigation component suggests that we should create a Navigation component by adding NavHost inside a Scaffold.

see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav

The problem that i have with this approach is that with this approach the bottom nav bar will be visible in all the screens. I want it to be visible in just the screens that are present in the bottom bar items.

Second approach of adding bottom bar would be to not add NavHost inside Scaffold. Instead Add Bottom Bar in one of theDestinations, then hide/show Composables from the body of the Scaffold based on the index selected like this.

```
var selectedBottomBarIndex by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
            MyBottomBar(currentIndex = selectedBottomBarIndex, onChanged = {
                    selectedBottomBarIndex = it
                }
            )
    } {
    when (selectedBottomBarIndex) {        
        0 -> HomeScreen(navController)
        1 -> AssignmentHomeScreen(navController)
        2 -> CategoryScreen(navController)
        else -> ProfileHomeScreen(navController)
    }
}
```

**I just want to know what are pros and cons of both the ways of adding bottom navigation.
and is the second approach safe to use in a production application.**

Comment: You can add flag to show/hide bottom bar in scaffod as well

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how to achieve it.

```
@Composable
fun JourneyApp() {
    JourneyTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val onBack: () -> Unit = {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
        val screens = listOf(
            Screen.Home,
            Screen.Collections,
            Screen.UserProfile
        )
        val showBottomBar = navController
            .currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination?.route in screens.map { it.route }
        // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                if (showBottomBar) {
                    BottomNavigation {
                        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                        val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
                        screens.forEach { screen ->
                            BottomNavigationItem(
                                icon = { Icon(imageVector = screen.icon, contentDescription = screen.label) },
                                label = { Text(screen.label) },
                                selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
                                onClick = {
                                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                                        // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                                        // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                                        // on the back stack as users select items
                                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                            saveState = true
                                        }
                                        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                                        // reselecting the same item
                                        launchSingleTop = true
                                        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                                        restoreState = true
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                // nav graph
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Home.route) {
                    // add new navigation function
                    composable(Screen.Home.route) { HomeScreen(navigateToImportPhoto = { navController.navigate("importPhoto") }) }
                    composable(Screen.Collections.route) { CollectionsScreen() }
                    composable(Screen.UserProfile.route) { UserProfileScreen() }
                    // new screen, not part of bottom nav
                    composable("importPhoto") { ImportPhotoScreen(onBack = onBack) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```